# DropdownList Not Showing Selected Item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a page to edit non-conformance reports. The page takes in a model which is as follows:

[image: enter code here]

On the page, I am trying to show a dropdown list with the current value of the `FaultCode` property pre-selected. However, it is not working. Instead I have stripped it back to the basics and tried to hard code a pre-selected value, as follows:

```
@{
                var faultCodeList = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Internal Damage", Value = "Internal Damage" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Customer Problem", Value = "Customer Problem"  },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Incorrect Material Supplied", Value = "Incorrect Material Supplied"  },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Received Material Damaged", Value = "Received Material Damaged"  },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "No Test Certificate Supplied", Value = "No Test Certificate Supplied" },
                    new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "Other", Selected = true}
                };
            }

            @Html.DropDownList("FaultCode", faultCodeList)
```

This still does not work. However, if I change the name of the field to something other than `FaultCode` - i.e `FaultCode2` - it works fine!

Why am I seeing this strange behaviour? On the same page I have dropdown lists for other fields, and they are working perfectly...

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Not showing what is supposed to be shown?

Comment: The "Other" entry is not selected - it defaults to the first item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.DropdownList("FaultCode", new SelectList(faultCodeList, "Value", "Text","Other"))
```

You need to bind to SelectList than List, so that last parameter you can mention the selected value is "Other".

Comment: ok, that seems to be working now (although you're missing a capital "D" in DropDown. I'm sure I had code like this earlier and it wasn't working...